# The method of my POST erase creation date time when i use the update function

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

When i pass the json on postman it creates the dependents with no problem, when i type an existing dependent with his Uuid to update the data the creationAt is set to null, and only the updateAt is set.

```
public void updatePreferencesAndDependents(UUID userId, UpdatePreferencesDependentsDTO updateDTO) {
        var user = getUserById(userId);
        user.setReferralHospital(updateDTO.getReferralHospital());
        user.setReferralHospitalId(updateDTO.getReferralHospitalId());
        user.setAttendance(updateDTO.getAttendance());
        user.setCoverage(updateDTO.getCoverage());
        user.setAccommodation(updateDTO.getAccommodation());
        user.setPartaking(updateDTO.getPartaking());
        user.setUserDependents(updateDTO.getUserDependents());
        var entity = UserMapper.mapper.toEntity(user);
        repository.save(entity);
    }
```

that i use in this endpoint:

```
 @PostMapping("/update-preferences-dependents")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO> updateDependentsAndPreferences(@RequestBody UpdatePreferencesDependentsDTO dto) {
        try {
            UUID userId = dto.getUuid();
            service.updatePreferencesAndDependents(userId, dto);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(response("User data updated."));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error updating data.", e.getMessage());
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(response("Error updating user data."));
        }
```

i have this mapper too:

```
@Named("UserMapper")
@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public interface UserMapper {
    UserMapper mapper = Mappers.getMapper(UserMapper.class);

    UserDTO toDto(UserEntity entity);

    UserEntity toEntity(UserDTO dto);

    List<UserDTO> toDto(List<UserEntity> entity);

    List<UserEntity> toEntity(List<UserDTO> dto);

}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "UserDependents")
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class UserDependentsEntity {

    @Id
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.UUIDCharType")
    private UUID uuid;

    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.UUIDCharType")
    private UUID userId;
    private String type;
    private String age;
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;
    private Boolean removed;

    @PreUpdate
    public void preUpdate() {
        this.updatedAt = LocalDateTimeUtil.now();
    }

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        this.uuid = CryptoUtil.generateUUID();
        this.createdAt = LocalDateTimeUtil.now();
    }
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserDependentsDTO {

    private UUID uuid;
    private UUID userId;
    private String type;
    private String age;

    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
    @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
    @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;
    private Boolean removed;
}
```

I tried adding an if in @prepersist and in the method too but it looks horrible

Comment: look here and example of my payload after i update an dependent:
 "userDependents": [
            {
                "uuid": "a888f64f-88f0-4ccd-b352-5f00388cb741",
                "userId": "ea30980b-518a-4240-0d8a-cf14lc10069k",
                "type": "Son",
                "age": "21",
                "createdAt": null,
                "updatedAt": "2023-04-27 09:38:26",
                "removed": null
            },

Comment: can you paste `UserDTO` class , does it have `createdAt` field ?

Comment: there you go ! :) thanks

Comment: Your method is taking UpdatePreferencesDependentsDTO and using that to populate an empty user data instance, which is then converted to an entity to be 'merged' into your existing entity. Everything in that converted Entity instance will overwrite the existing managed entity data - even the properties you've left blank. You need to set the UpdatePreferencesDependentsDTO data into the entity instance from the database directly, so that you only overwrite the specific fields you intend to set with the new data. Alternatively, you can mark createdAt with updateable=false

Answer (score 0):

looks like in update method `updatePreferencesAndDependents`
You assign dependatns data from postman to `user`
`user.setUserDependents(updateDTO.getUserDependents());` if postman does not sends `createdAt` it will be null, and if postman sends any value it will override value from db

Comment: exactly, frontend will pass the creationat and its ok! thank yooou